# When playing "Play with a friend" anonymously on Lichess with "Real Time" time control, does minutes per side get carried over?

Tags: time-control, lichess

[image]

Does the remaining part of "x minutes per side" get carried over if a side does a move in less than x minutes? i.e. if it's 3 minutes per side & I finish a move in 1 minute, will my remaining 2 minutes get carried over to the next move - i.e. will I get 5 minutes for the next move?

I want to create a game where each move gets completed in max 'x' minutes - is there a way to do that. Also, I am not sure how the "increment" affects this but I guess I can set it 0 so it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time is *total*, so for the whole *game*, not per move. If you run out, you lose (or, if the opponent has only a bare king or similar, it's occassionally a draw).

After each move, the "increment" gets added to the time. So when you run really low on time, you'll at least have that many seconds per move.

So yes, it gets carried over. You can create a "1 minute per move" game by setting the initial time to 1 minute and increment to 60 seconds, but if people move faster then they will have longer for the next move.

This is called a "Fischer" increment, it was his invention. What you want is called "Bronstein" time delay. Unfortunately I've never seen an online chess site that implements that, it's always Fischer style.

Comment: Thank you. What would be a good time + increment to keep for a casual game in Lichess. I don't want to play speed chess but I also don't want the other player to wander away to do other stuff during the game. Neither players are beginners but neither are they very good. I want the game to finish in around 45 minutes.

Comment: 15 minutes plus 10 seconds perhaps? Average game takes 40 moves so that's a bit more than 20 minutes for each side. Anyway, just try things out...